# i have wallet's keystore file and private key. how can i find mnemonic words

Tags: keystore, mnemonic

I have keystore file and private key of my wallet. i need this wallet's mnemonic words.

How can i find mnemonic phrase from this json file and private key? I tried mycrypto and mew but i couldnt find a solution. I need these words.

Please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get a mnemonic phrase from a private key?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/62530/how-can-i-get-a-mnemonic-phrase-from-a-private-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't generate your mnemonic from your private key. the encryption algorithm is one-way. They are called “one-way hash functions” because there is no way to reverse the encryption.