# Creating Metamask wallets using a script

Tags: web3js, metamask, wallets

Can we create like 100-200 metamask wallets using api or any script?

Answer (score 0):

Metamask uses "Hierarchical Deterministic Wallets", see [What is a HD wallet for Ether and how to create one using nodejs?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/33395/what-is-a-hd-wallet-for-ether-and-how-to-create-one-using-nodejs).

There are several libraries that you can use to manage and create thousands of addresses. Fo example in javascript there is [ethereumjs-wallet](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet).